# Two-way computed property (get,set) with 20+ properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that has 20+ properties that I want to convert to two-way computer properties like below. Problem is that sole list of those properties is quite long (actually 28) so converting all of them will be really repetitive and will take a lot of unnecessary space. Is there any trick I don't know that can make it look clean?

```
   computed: {
       exp: {
          get () {
             return this.job.exp
          },
          set (value) {
             this.$emit('job', { exp: value })
          }
       },

       fund: {
          get () {
             return this.job.fund
          },
          set (value) {
             return this.$emit('job', { fund: value})
          }
       },
       // more to come
    }
```

Below method that is used when `this.$emit('job', arg)` is emitted:

```
updateJob (object, source) {
      for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)){

        this.job[key]
          ? this.job[key] = value
          : this.$set(this.job, key, value)
      }
    },
```

Comment: I don't know if this works in Vue, but if you iterate over your `job` object, making each property return an object with a `get` and `set` methods, would it work?

Comment: Why if you share the `job` object and you update the whole object always instead each property. Is that fit your case? I don't know the context you are using this approach...

Comment: @The.Bear I'm actually updating only thing that changed without touching other properties. I want parent to be the source of truth for children and that's why I'm getting rid of duplicating parent's data in child component because it causes trouble following the logic.

Comment: @jeand'arme Ok, I'm talking about something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/uvxwh2o0/30/ Also you can use v-model to share the `job`. I will provide a full answer if that way could solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let computed;
let list = ["exp", "fund"];

this.$emit = (s, value) => {
    let key = Object.keys(value)[0];
    this.job[key] = value[key];
}

this.job = {
    exp: 20
}

list.map((v) => {
    computed = {
        ...computed,
        [v]: {
            get: () => {
                return this.job[v];
            },
            set: (value) => {
                return this.$emit('job', { [v]: value });
            }
        }
    }
})

console.log("get", computed.exp.get());
computed.exp.set(10);
console.log("get", computed.exp.get());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`$watch` api](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) with the `deep: true` option. Here's a basic implementation with an increment function:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    job: {
      a: 11,
      b: 22,
      c: 33,
      d: 44,
      e: 55,
      f: 66,
      g: 77,
      h: 88,
      // ...
    },
  },
  created() {
    // use $watch interface with the deep option
    this.$watch('job', (newVal, oldVal) => {
      // check for changes from the previous state
      Object.keys(newVal).forEach(key => {
        if(newVal[key] !== oldVal[key]) {
          console.log('changed job attr', key, newVal[key])
          this.$emit('job', {[key]: newVal[key]})
        }
      })
    }, {deep: true})
  },
  methods: {
    increment(key) {
      // needs to be reassigned rather than mutated if you want
      // the $watch callback to get the correct oldVal
      const val = this.job[key] + 1
      this.job = Object.assign({}, this.job, {[key]: val})
    }
  },
})
```

html to demo the increment function:

```
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(val, key) in job" :key="key" @click="increment(key)">
      {{ key }}: {{ val }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the `get`/`set` approach so that you can use `v-model`. Personally I would probably ditch the `v-model` and use the separate prop/event pair.

However, that isn't to say that generating repeated computed properties cannot be done:

```js
const properties = ['exp', 'fund']
const computed = {}

for (const property of properties) {
  computed[property] = {
    get () {
      return this.job[property]
    },
    
    set (value) {
      this.$emit('job', { [property]: value })
    }
  }
}

const Child = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <input v-model="exp">
      <input v-model="fund">
    </div>
  `,
  
  props: ['job'],
  
  computed: {
    ...computed
    // other computed properties here
  }  

}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    Child
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      job: {
        exp: 'hello',
        fund: 'goodbye'
      }
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    updateJob (changes) {
      for (const property in changes) {
        this.$set(this.job, property, changes[property])
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <Child :job="job" @job="updateJob"></Child>
  <pre>{{ job }}</pre>
</div>
```

Each computed property just needs an object with a `get` and `set` method. It's important to realise that these are not `get` and `set` in the `defineProperty` sense. Instead they are just normal methods that happen to be called `get` and `set`.

We need one such object for each computed property, so we create them in a loop and add them all to an object (which I've called `computed`) that holds all of these computed properties.

Then, in the component definition, these properties are spread using the `...` operator. Strictly speaking the spreading isn't necessary unless there are other computed properties that aren't present in that object.

You could move all of the code for building the computed properties inline under the `computed` property, rather than having it at the start. There are two ways to do that, either by using `reduce` or by wrapping it all in an IIFE than returns the relevant object. To my mind that would look a bit unwieldy so I've kept it outside instead.